# Clicking Specific CasperJS Button Not Working

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, automated-tests, casperjs

I am using the following code in a long script many times:

```
this.click("<selector>");
```

But there is one page that doesn't work, and I don't understand why.

The HTML is:

```
<div class="bottom-row">
 <div class="actions-primary">                                                                                                                                                                                
   <button class="add-subscription button middle" id="2">Choose</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

So I am using:

```
casper.waitUntilVisible('#products_screen',
    function success() {
        casper.test.pass('Product List Show');
        this.echo(this.getHTML('.actions-primary'));
        //this.click("button#2.add-subscription.button.middle");
        this.click("#2");
    },
    function fail() {
        casper.test.fail('List of Products not showing');
    },
50000);
```

I tried all possible selectors with no luck.

Also, if I try with Resurrectio in Chrome, it doesn't record the click.

Any workaround is welcome.

**SOLUTION UPDATE:**

```
this.click('[id="2"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it using css selector format:

```
this.click('[id="2"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

If an `id` is a number, you must either escape the number based on the Unicode code point, or use the attribute selector.

**Both of the following solutions will work:**

```
this.click('#\\32 ');    // Escaped based on Unicode code point
this.click('[id="2"]');  // Attribute selector
```